# Grabbing ETOY PlayingCardDeck

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm trying to make a game that includes playing cards.
I have a sub class of BorderedMorph that I added to all of the decks.
I have sub class of PlayingCardDeck that I implemented the game deck behaviour in.
I didn't touched all of the dragging and dropping features in the subclass, and I get the same error you get when you try to drag and drop this:

```
g:= PlayingCardDeck new.
g newDeck.
g layout: #pile.
g openInWorld.
```

how can I repair this bug and make my game draggable, so I will be able to move it on screen (not only by pressing the scroll wheel in).

the problem is in the PlayingCardMorph because when I try to move empty deck I can do it.

Comment: What's exactly the error you get?

Comment: I've taken a look. The problem is that there is no board involved. You should study other games to see how to create a board and put the cards on it.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I got error : PasteUpMorph >> CaptureStateBeforeGrab
I have a board, when I extend the board more then the place that the cards take I can grab only by the board and move. I don't want the decks them selfs to be able to be dragged. can I remove the dragging ability from the cards & board and then I will be able to pick up by all of the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok my issue is resolved.
the solution for me was to make sub class for PlayingCardMorph
and adding the following method:

```
handlesMouseDown: aMouse
    ^false
```

hope it helps any one that needs it.